# Python threading basics on console application - Correct way to terminate thread/s

Tags: python, multithreading

I'm looking for the best way to handle a python console threading application with the possibility to exit at (say) Ctrl+C

This is my code.

```
from threading import Thread
import time 
import sys


class MyPrint(Thread):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MyPrint, self).__init__()
        self.WhatToPrint = "Iteration"
        self.running = True

    def run(self):
        Counter = 0
        a, b = 0, 1
        print("\tFibonacci - START")
        while self.running:
            print("\t{} {} - {}".format(self.WhatToPrint, Counter, a))
            Counter += 1
            a, b = b, a + b
            time.sleep(0.2)

    def stop(self):
        self.running = False
        print("\tFibonacci - END")


def Main() -> int:  
    print("Main Start")
    oMyPrint = MyPrint()
    oMyPrint.start()
    oMyPrint.join(1)

    try:
        while True:
            time.sleep(0.1)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        oMyPrint.stop()
        print("Main End")
        return 0

if __name__ == '__main__':
    sys.exit(Main())
```

It works, but I'm sure it can be improved a lot. I'd like your suggestions to start with the right foot.
Thanks

Comment: Nothing inherently wrong with the code. I feel this question fits more on codereview.stackexchange.com as you don't have a specific problem

Comment: It's fine. I am not sure why you are doing the initial call to `oMyPrint.join(1)` . Also, Instead of calling `time.sleep(0.01)`, consider instead `oMyPrint.join(.1)` and then testing to see if the thread completed for some reason with a call to `oMyPrint.is_alive()`. This way if for some reason your thread has terminated (exception?), you are not doing any unnecessary extra sleeping.